# How can I run a doctrine 2 migration commandline without interaction?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, doctrine, phpunit

How can I run a doctrine 2 migration command without interaction?

Currently I have following command which runs on the setup of my Unit Tests. But It always prompt for a Yes/No user input, even when I use the --no-interaction option.

```
$input = new Symfony\Components\Console\Input\ArrayInput(
        array(
            'migrations:migrate',
            '--configuration' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../doctrine/migrations.xml',
            '--no-interaction',
            )
        );
$cli->run($input);
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I just stumbled over your post, as I was having the same problem. Doctrine Migrations seem to been updated meanwhile (I guess: https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/commit/5b2751f149bc38d38870578f753c2193eb36e742).

Hence

```
 php app/console --no-interaction doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

now works fine.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 12):

I don't like Tom his approach and there is a other way to get this done:

```
<?php
$input = new Symfony\Components\Console\Input\ArrayInput(
    array(
        'migrations:migrate',
        '--configuration' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../doctrine/migrations.xml',
    )
);
$input->setInteractive(false);
?>
```